# SP Hosted Addins - Use for large Clent Side systems

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, workflow, spfx, sharepoint-framework

The business logic from employee is medium-bigger. I want to know for SharePoint-Hosted add-ins are designed for large software systems using JSOM - (workflows, CRUD operations and ect.) using SharePoint Addin template from Visual Studio... I want to use SPFx, but documentation and release are at an early stage..

- What is the best solution to create large system for cloud and
  on-premise using sharepoint functionally?